# Why VisitorIdentification.js file is missing?

Tags: xdb

Is there any reason why `\layouts\system\VisitorIdentification.js` file or whole `\layouts\system\` folder is missing on the Sitecore instance?

I'm using `Sitecore 10.2` on my local and I can see this file, this file is missing on the test server. So I wondering does Sitecore provides some installation option that will not install this file or this file should always be present after any kind of Sitecore installation?

Comment: That isn't a real file. It's dynamically served by Sitecore when and as needed. Alternatively someone removed it. You're not sharing any details that would allow anyone to answer.

Comment: @MarkCassidy I updated the question with details, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your statement in your question i.e. "**this file should always be present after any kind of Sitecore installation**", I downloaded `Sitecore 10.2` installation packages for `Sitecore Experience Platform (XP)` and `Sitecore Experience Management (XM)`.

After extracting I found that the folder called **System** that is under **Layout** doesn't exist in `XM` but it does exist in `XP`. And I also verified that for both `Content Management (CM)` and `Content Delivery (CD)` packages. So it exists in `XP` for both `CM` and `CD` but not in XM for both.

So you need to verify on your test server, which one is installed over there.

To check the feature available for `XM` and `XP`, please follow this link.

https://getfishtank.ca/blog/sitecore-xm-vs-xp

Also, I verified these packages.

[image]

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

I checked in Sitecore 10.2 vanilla instance **(Sitecore.NET 10.2.0 (rev. 006766)
)** in that this file as folder both are present under **sc10.local/layouts/system** layouts folder see below screenshot

[image]

May be it got removed by mistake or intentionally if not needed for project.